# How does Rename command decide what string literals to change?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The `Rename __ to __` command in Visual Studio (<kbd>CTRL - .</kbd> after renaming a declaration) not only renames members and direct dependencies, but to my recent surprise also references to those members in string literals. This is simultaneously useful and scary.

What rules is the Rename command following when altering string literals? Is it equivalent to a simple search and replace, or something slightly more sophisticated? I'm concerned of wholesale changes with false positives in larger projects, however if the operation is smart enough in a predictable way then I'm inclined to use it.

Comment: That's interesting, it *does not* change any string literals that contain the same text when I do it.  What do you mean by "references to those members in string literals"?

Comment: Are you using any tools like Resharper?

Comment: @PeterRitchie It's a setting that can be enabled or disabled.  It is disabled by default, he turned it on.

Comment: Not using Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

When renaming using refactor -> rename, if you don't want to search string literals for the name and replace it then in the rename dialog uncheck "search in strings", to not replace uses of that variable in comments uncheck "search in comments".  If you want to see what would change to check for false positives then check "preview reference changes" so you can verify that they are all correct.

Comment: I don't see that option in either of the two renames you can do from Ctrl+. (or Shift+Alt+F10)

Comment: I *do* see it in Edit/Refactor/Rename (or F2), but the OP detailed using Ctrl+.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how does it perform the search and replace with the string literals? For instance simply a source code search and replace for "\*membername\*", or "\*.membername\*", or something smarter?

Comment: @DuckMaestro It appears to search on word boundaries.